# Ionic build fails Info.plist not found

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, xcode10

Apple has tricked me and even though I disabled autoupdates it now pulled the most recent XCode version (Version 10.0 (10A255)) and dependencies. The effect is that I can not build my app anymore, even after removing (`ionic cordova platform remove ios`) and re-adding the platform.

It now fails with the error below.

```
onic cordova run ios --debug --target="iPhone-8"  --consolelogs

...

<path>/platforms/ios/build/emulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist file not found.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run ios --debug --target iPhone-8 (exit code 1).

ionic --version
3.20.0
```

---- EDIT

ran with `verbose` and received :`No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".` as additional info for the failure.

----- EDIT ------

Please look here for more detail. I was able to reproduce it from scratch / a blank app template
[Blank app fails debug build - /Info.plist file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584550/blank-app-fails-debug-build-info-plist-file-not-found)

Comment: Info.plist is a file which is a must for an ios app to build, please check manually by going to your project location ../iOS and look for .plist file.

Comment: The `ios/build` folder is missing. I found a `MyApp-Info.plist` in the `ios/MyApp` folder. Created a symbolic link `Info.plist` to that file, no avail. Not sure why the whole build folder is not being generated?

Comment: Is there a way to run the `*.plist` generating script again? It seems to be missing...

Comment: you have to open code using xcode. there you can create a plist file with all the permissions and version detail of the app

Comment: The plist file is in `<path>/MyApp/platforms/ios/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist`. However, it is not being copied nowhere... @Ashwani - any idea how to get it copied automatically during build?

Comment: This link may solve you're problem. https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407. Xcode10 isn't supported by Cordova as of right now.

Answer (score 16):

**ionic cordova emulate ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"**

Try this command it should work,this is issue with cordova.

Comment: This command worked for me. cordova run ios doesn't work for me and it does not launch the emulator. This is cordova cli v 8 and Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 14):

If you're building on the command-line, try this

**ionic cordova emulate ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"**

or

**Xcode 10**

If you are opening the project in the Xcode IDE, you need to change the build system in Workspace Settings to "Legacy Build System"

**Xcode example**

[image]

[image]

Now, You can also run this on command-line **$ionic cordova build ios**

Best of luck