# Ionic Cordova won't emulate iOS - No scripts found for hook

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to build an iOS app using Ionic. I have used Ionic 1 and 3 and I get the same error with both. When I try to run `ionic cordova emulate ios --verbose` I get the following error:

```
Updating Storyboard image set contents.json
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared iOS project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
Building for iPhone XS Max Simulator
Building project: /Users/Jackson/Desktop/Capstone/research_app/todo/platforms/ios/todo.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/Jackson/Desktop/Capstone/research_app/todo/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/Jackson/Desktop/Capstone/research_app/todo/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/Jackson/Desktop/Capstone/research_app/todo/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h

No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-XS-Max, 12.0 simulator
/Users/Jackson/Desktop/Capstone/research_app/todo/platforms/ios/build/emulator/todo.app/Info.plist file not found.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova emulate ios --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: process.exit received +0ms
  ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions +0ms
  ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: exiting (exit code 1) +40ms
```

Answer (score 4):

```
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
```

This is not an error message, it's just a log message:

The actual error message is:

`/Users/Jackson/Desktop/Capstone/research_app/todo/platforms/ios/build/emulator/todo.app/Info.plist file not found.`

But it's misleading. The actual problem is that `cordova-ios@4` is currently not compatible with the new build system in Xcode 10, which is used by default.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52588028/777265) for a solution.