# building cordova app sudently stopped working

Tags: cordova, bridging-header

Since I installed the last version of XCode 10.0 I get the following error when trying to build my cordova ios app:

```
Building for iPhone XS Max Simulator
Building project:     /Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/test/platforms/ios/HelloCordova.xcworkspace
    Configuration: Debug
    Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR =     /Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/test/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.0
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/test/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file     '/Users/patrick/Desktop/VMSharedFolder/test/platforms/ios/cordova/build-    debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS =     $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"     "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
```

Not sure where this comes from, I am using cordova 8.1.2 and have the following plugins installed.

```
code-push 2.0.6 "CodePushAcquisition"
com.telerik.cordovaPlatformSpecificFiles 0.1.0 "Cordova Platform Specific Files"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 1.2.0 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-code-push 1.11.12 "CodePush"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.3 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.5 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.5 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-insomnia 4.3.0 "Insomnia (prevent screen sleep)"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.6 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-media 2.4.1 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.4.1 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2-dev "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-vibration 2.1.3 "Vibration"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
```

However I get the same error even if I create a new empty project then add the ios platform and try to build it.

Any help would be welcome.

Comment: I don't see any error is your build log extract, but at a guess: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52588028/777265

Comment: Thanks, the trick was what I was looking for. It works indeed adding the parameter mentioned in you link